# Reading a javascript object as JSON on POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I read that "javascript is JSON" in other SO posts.  I am having difficulty translating this theory to my application.  I perform a POST with jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Pricing/Create',
        data: items,
        success: function () { alert('successfully called pricing'); },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

The post successfully hits the breakpoint in my `PricingController`'s `Create` method.  In reviewing my `Request.QueryString`, it is empty.

`items` is an array of `SomeItem` with `length = 30`.  Defined as

```
function SomeItem(description, finalPrice, percentDiscount) {
    this.Description = description;
    this.FinalPrice = finalPrice;
    this.PercentDiscount = percentDiscount;
}
```

I perform no JSON conversion because "javascript is JSON".  How do I get to my data in the Pricing Controller?

---

Almost there. When `JSON.stringify(items)` runs I see a nice set of junk in my alert() (also pretty in Firebug):

`[{"Description":"some item","Data2":"$1.00","data3":"10"},//...`

But, when it arrives on the server...in C# `Request.Form` it looks like:

`%5b%7b%22Description%22%3a%22some+item%22%2c%22data2%22` wtflip is that...

Comment: "JSON is JavaScript," Alice hastily replied; "at least JavaScript is JSON--that's the same thing, you know." "Not a bit!" said Resig. "You might just as well say that 'JQuery is JavaScript' is the same thing as 'JavaScript is jQuery'!" "You might just as well say," added Gruber, "that 'XHTML is XML' is the same thing as 'XML is XHTML'!" "You might just as well say," added Internet Explorer, which seemed to be talking in its sleep, "that 'ActiveXObject is an XMLHttpRequest object' is the same as 'the XMLHttpRequest object is an ActiveXObject'!" "It *IS* the same thing with you," said Resig.

Comment: While JSON can be seen as JavaScript, transporting values back and forth over the wire is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `JSON.stringify()` ?

You can change your data line to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(items),
```

If the target browser doesn't natively support `JSON.stringify()`, you can Google for a library to fill in that feature.

Comment: +1 I am now using the `JSON.stringify(items)`.  The data is coming in now.  It looks good in Firebug.  But, in `Request.Form`, where the object lies it is trashed.  There's a lot of `%5b%7b%22` gibberish.  Not sure what it is.  `HtmlDecode` didn't fix it.  Whatever the issue, `JavaScriptSerializer` cant Deserialize: Error "Invalid JSON primitive:".

Comment: that would be `[{"`. You don't want to `HtmlDecode` that, you want to `UrlDecode` it, though it has been be experience that MVC3 fixed the JSON decoding bits. If not, James Newton-King's Json.NET is a superior JavsScript serializer/deserializer in my experience.

Comment: I never even heard of `UrlDecode`!  Geez, no wonder.  Thanks, you saved my face off!  You rock

Answer (score 5):

JSON is 'JavaScript Object Notation', not JavaScript. You use JSON to represent a JavaScript object, especially when you want to send it back to a server.

You do need to convert your JavaScript object to JSON before passing it to the ajax call - this should do the trick:

```
var json = $.toJSON(items);
```

Have a read of this, it might help: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: `JSON.stringify(...)` is better than `$.toJSON(...)` the reason is mentioned in the blog post

Comment: Although related, which is better is not the point of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you used the POST method, then it's not going to be in the QueryString variable. If you watch what is going on with a fiddler-like tool, is your data (items) being passed back in the body of the request? If so, then you should be able to access it.  Otherwise, something is wrong with your AJAX request.

Comment: +1 Ah, ok.  I'm so used to doing $.get() I didnt even think about this.  In FireBug I see 30 key/value pairs all set to `undefined`.